# How to get sidebar that is resizeable and collapsible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to implement side navigation bar which is resize able and has a button on the bar i.e. on clicking the button the side navigation should open and again on clicking the button it should get close.
I am not able to implement the button part on the bar.
Can you please help me..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>AngularJS Navigation</title>
<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
</script>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" data-semver="2.0.3" data-require="jquery"></script>
<script data-semver="1.2.13" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js" data-require="angular.js@1.2.x"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="resizer.js"></script>

</head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <div id="topnav">Top navbar</div>

  <div id="sidebar">
    <h3>Side Navbar</h3>
  </div>

  <div id="content">

    <div id="top-content">Top content <p>{{content}}</p></div>

    <div id="content-resizer" 
        resizer="horizontal" 
        resizer-height="6" 
        resizer-top="#top-content" >
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="sidebar-resizer" 
    resizer="vertical" 
    resizer-width="6" 
    resizer-left="#sidebar" 
    resizer-right="#content"
    resizer-max="100%">
   </div>

   </body>

   </html>
```

Code of "app.js"

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp', ['mc.resizer']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.content = 'Hello World';
});
```

Code of "resizer.js"

```
 angular.module('mc.resizer', []).directive('resizer', function($document) {

    return function($scope, $element, $attrs) {

        $element.on('mousedown', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            $document.on('mousemove', mousemove);
            $document.on('mouseup', mouseup);
        });

        function mousemove(event) {

            if ($attrs.resizer == 'vertical') {
                // Handle vertical resizer
                var x = event.pageX;

                if ($attrs.resizerMax && x > $attrs.resizerMax) {
                    x = parseInt($attrs.resizerMax);
                }

                $element.css({
                    left: x + 'px'
                });

                $($attrs.resizerLeft).css({
                    width: x + 'px'
                });
                $($attrs.resizerRight).css({
                    left: (x + parseInt($attrs.resizerWidth)) + 'px'
                });

            } else {
                // Handle horizontal resizer
                var y = window.innerHeight - event.pageY;

                }
        }

        function mouseup() {
            $document.unbind('mousemove', mousemove);
            $document.unbind('mouseup', mouseup);
        }
    };
});
```

Code of "style.css"

```
#topnav {
    background-color: #333333;
    display: block;
    height: 35px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #DDD;
}

#sidebar {
    background-color: #AEE;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}
#content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 205px /* 200 + 6*/;
    right: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #FFF;

}
#top-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0px; /* 130 + 6 */
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #444;
    overflow: auto;
}

#sidebar-resizer {
    background-color: #666;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 200px;
    width: 5px;
    cursor: e-resize;
}
#content-resizer {
    position: absolute;
    height: 6px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #666;
    cursor: n-resize;
}

#sidebar-resizer:hover, #preview-resizer:hover {
    background-color: #AAA;
}
```

Comment: Please post some of your JS code, what you've tried. This is just an HTML page, it is not enough for you to get some help!

Comment: @sjahan I have updated the question. Please have a look. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: @sjahan It's a sidenav bar

Comment: First of all, i've set up a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4dxjfxd9/
Second point: are you sure your angularJS app is running? In the fiddle, nothing happened at first (the `content` scope variable was not set, i didn't see Hello World). I've added `ng-app` so that it starts, are you sure your application is starting?

Answer (score 1):

try this hope it helps ng-init used for initializing the state of sidebar

```
<button type="button" ng-click="toggleSideBar=!toggleSideBar">Click Me!</button>
<div id="sidebar" ng-show="toggleSideBar" ng-init="toggleSideBar=true">
    <h3>Side Navbar</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
/* Set the width of the side navigation to 250px */
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

/* Set the width of the side navigation to 0 */
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
/* The side navigation menu */
.sidenav {
    height: 100%; /* 100% Full-height */
    width: 0; /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
    top: 0; /* Stay at the top */
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111; /* Black*/
    overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
    padding-top: 60px; /* Place content 60px from the top */
    transition: 0.5s; /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidenav */
}

/* The navigation menu links */
.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Position and style the close button (top right corner) */
.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

/* Style page content - use this if you want to push the page content to the right when you open the side navigation */
#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 20px;
}

/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
    .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<!-- Use any element to open the sidenav -->
<span onclick="openNav()">open</span>

<!-- Add all page content inside this div if you want the side nav to push page content to the right (not used if you only want the sidenav to sit on top of the page -->
<div id="main">
  ...
</div>
```

*Try this example. Hope this works.. Please comment below for any questions*

Comment: Thank you for this code but I want the button to be implemented on the vertical bar not should not appear separately i.e. on click the vertical bar the bar should open and on again clicking the vertical bar it should get close.

Answer (score 1):

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #3498DB;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #2980B9;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd}

/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
.show {display:block;}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Adjust the height and width of the dropdown button as your wish for responsive look. Hope this meets your requirements. Comment for any questions.

Comment: It's not a dropdown, but a sidenav bar